# Functions calling before data is loaded in angular

Tags: angular, http, lifecycle

Hi there I am a little new to angular and I am having trouble with loading data.
In the snippet of code below I have two services getting called. In each service I output something to the console. After both of the services run I have a piece of code that outputs my order number to the console an additional time. However every time I run this. It blazes thru ngOnInit and puts out the info below in the console. How can i tell the last console output to wait until the first two services are completely done.

- order undefined
- array of depots Test Depot Name
- length of depots 18

  ```
  ngOnInit(): void {
  //called first
  this.dataService.sendGetRequest().subscribe((data: any[]) => {
    this.orderInfoList = data;
    console.log("array of depots "+ this.orderInfoList.depots[1].name);
    console.log("length of depots "+ this.orderInfoList.depots.length);
  })
  //called second
  this.dataService.getOrder(+this.orderId).subscribe((data: any[]) => {
    this.order = data;
    console.log("order " + this.order.orderNumber);
  })
  //entered last
  console.log("order " + this.order.orderNumber);
  ```

  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data service functions are asynchronous, so you need to run them asynchronously. Since `getOrder` doesn't depend on the result of `sendGetRequest`, you can run them in parallel using `forkJoin`.

They will both be executed, and the subscribe will only run once both have completed.

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
  forkJoin({
    getRequest: this.dataService.sendGetRequest(),
    order: this.dataService.getOrder(+this.orderId)
  }).subscribe(result => {
    this.orderInfoList = result.getRequest;
    this.order = result.order;

    console.log("array of depots "+ this.orderInfoList.depots[1].name);
    console.log("length of depots "+ this.orderInfoList.depots.length);
    console.log("order " + this.order.orderNumber);
  });
}
```

`forkJoin` also accepts an array of observables:

```js
forkJoin([
  this.dataService.sendGetRequest(), 
  this.dataService.getOrder(+this.orderId)
]).subscribe(result => {
  this.orderInfoList = result[0];
  this.order = result[1];
});
```